# How to get a response from a jsp page using $http.get in AngularJS?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, json

I am new to JSON and $http service in AngularJS. I am trying to get a response from a jsp file(which is in same folder). But when I run it on the server nothing is printed. Also there are no errors.

Somebody please help. Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Below is my html file where I've used AngularJS:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.js"> </script>
    <script>
    var myApp=angular.module("myApp",[]);
    myApp.controller("myController",function($scope,$http){

        $http.get("JSON.jsp").then(function(response){
            $scope.array=response;

        }).then(function(error){
            console.log(error, 'can not get data.');
        });

    });

    </script>


    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>AngularCheck</title>

    </head>
    <body ng-controller="myController" >
    <div ng-repeat="arr in array">
    {{arr.name}} 
    {{arr.age}}


    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Below is my jsp file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>JSON page</title>
</head>
<body>


<%

out.println(" [{\"name\":\"jothi\",\"age\":\"20\"},{\"name\":\"Guru\",\"age\":\"22\"}]");

%>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To get a more meaningful response, please post the complete error message as well.

Comment: @jan.vdbergh "Also there are no errors."

Comment: @jdgregson First I've used .then(function()).After changing it to .catch there are no errors. But still when i run it on the server nothing is printed.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `catch` to get the error message instead of `then`

```
$http.get("JSON.jsp").then(function(response){
   $scope.array=response.data;

}).catch(function(error){
   console.log(error, 'can not get data.');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sachila. I've changed it to catch. But still nothing is printed in the webpage. It seems nothing is stored inside '$scope.array' object.

Comment: you need to access the `data` property. change it `$scope.array=response.data`

Comment: Sir the result is the same even after changing it to '$scope.array=response.data' . Can you please run this code on your machine and share me the result?